# How to mock a field in superclass using Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a `MyClass` which has some field `MyService myService`.

Now, I'm testing the class by extending it. i.e. `MyClassTest extends MyClass`.

My question is, how do I tell Mockito to mock `myService`?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you test a class extending it? Anyway, the only way I see is passing the dependency (the mocked service) to the constructor of the base class with super.

Comment: How do you initialize this field? Can you assign a value with a setter?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov, basically it's `@Autowired`. I could add setter or more suitable, another ctor()

Comment: @burm87, I do so because most of the methods are private. One could argue that this is a bad design. I could agree on that

Comment: You say `@Autowired`. Is this in Spring or Spring Boot? You can provide the mock to the Spring context with `@MockBean` and run the test using `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@SpringBootTest`. Or you can do the autowiring via the ctor instead of directly on the field.

Comment: You should provide a minimized example that describes those two classes and your test configuration, like one test. For example: I am interested how extending a class helps testing private methods. Answers you already got might work but maybe question could also be more useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this field is not accessible from outside, you have two options: reflection and... reflection.

Example 1:
using `org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldSetter`.

```
MyClass m = new MyClass();
FieldSetter.setField(m, m.getClass().getDeclaredField("myService"), yourService);
```

Example 2:
standard Java's reflection:

```
MyClass m = new MyClass();
Field f = m.getClass().getDeclaredField("myService");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.set(m, yourService);
```

Comment: side note : FieldSetter was deprecated at some point and now this class is no longer usable

Answer (score 1):

You can mock the service as below.

These are the imports you should have

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
```

Here is the test

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

// Mock the service
MyService myService = mock(MyService.class);
// Write the behavior of the mocked service.
when(myService.myMethod()).thenReturn(someOutputObjectThatShouldBeReturned)

// Set the mocked service to your class.
Whitebox.setInternalState(myClass, "myService", myService)
```